# How to turn off and on heartbeat service when haproxy is turned off and on?

Tags: haproxy, ubuntu-14.04, heartbeat, init

I'd like the heartbeat service to turn off before haproxy is stopped and to turn on before it starts on a Ubuntu 14.04 Server. What is the best way to accomplish this? I'm sure one of these days I'm going to forget the proper order and so try not to depend on the keenness of my own memory.

Comment: So you want to tie those two services in a way if you run service haproxy stop, so that it stops heartbeat first, or you just want to ensure proper order on server boot and shutdown?

Comment: The first, boot order is fine.